# Add custom attribute set to customer

Tags: magento-enterprise

I want to create new a new attribute group for customer and then I want to add new attributes for that group. Can any one help me.
I am able to add custom attributes for customers, customer address. But I want to add my new group `custom group` against customer and then want to add my custom attribute1 ,attribute2 for that group. Can any one help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new attribute set by going to Catalog > Manage Attribute Sets.

In Attribute Set create a custom Attribute Group and add your custom attributes to it.

Create a new product and select your desired attribute set. You can also edit the existing products and change the attribute set.

Comment: I want create attribute group for customers

Comment: Check these links [link1](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5905/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer-registration-form) [link2](https://www.fontis.com.au/blog/know-more-about-your-customers-adding-custom-signup-attributes)