# Is there any option to add custom attributes in customer registration form from admin panel?

Tags: attributes, customer, register

I wish to create new fields in the customer registration form. I just wanted to know whether there is any option to create it from Magento admin panel.

Kindly guide me as am new to magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, There is no option to create it from admin. You will need to create custom script to create it. You can follow below module steps to create custom attribute.

**app/code/local/Custom/Customerattribute/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Customerattribute>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Custom_Customerattribute>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <customerattribute_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Custom_Customerattribute</module>
                    <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </customerattribute_setup>
            <customerattribute_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </customerattribute_write>
            <customerattribute_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </customerattribute_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Custom/Customerattribute/sql/customerattribute_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("customer", "custom_attribute",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Custom Attribute",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "custom_attribute");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();



$installer->endSetup();
```

And finally declare your module

**app/etc/modules/Custom_Customerattribute.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Custom_Customerattribute>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Custom_Customerattribute>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**You can change your attribute code and label as per your requirement.**

Comment: Thank you so much your reply..! But still the custom attribute is not displayed in the frontend.

Comment: it will not display automatically in front-end. you will need to call it in template file manually.

Comment: Yes I called (<?php $_age = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_age') ?>
        <?php if ($_age->isEnabled()): ?>
            <li><?php echo $_age->setAge($this->getCustomer()->getAge())->toHtml() ?></li>
        <?php endif ?>) in form/edit.phtml and form/register.phtml as I wish to include a field for 'age'

Comment: you can call it like <input type="text" name="age" id="age" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getAge()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Age')) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />

Comment: Thank you. but still I didn't get it. Is there anything else that should be done since am using Magento version 1.9.2.2?

Comment: do you mean form is not showing field after placing above line of code ?

Comment: Yes. I followed Your code from the beginning till your last comment.

Comment: did you check you are making changes in correct template file? also attribute is showing in backend or not ?

Comment: I have made changes in app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/customer/form/edit.phtml & register.phtml.And  at the backend it is not showing up in System/customers/customer configuration.

Comment: Hey I got it. Thank you so much for your help. I just forgot to make the changes in app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml. Now 'Age' field is visible in the form at frontend. Should it be visible at the backend also?

Comment: did you added above module in your setup? did you able to see your age attribute in customer account section in admin?

Comment: Yea in customer/account Information section am able to see the new field. Thank you so much. But to check whether it is working, I just applied your code exactly, The field is in the name 'Custom Attribute'. Today I have changed It to 'Age' but it is not changed at the backend.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the rep to comment, so I had to answer.

There is no way from admin panel as such. But you can do that custom

I am assuming it for magento 1. And I think the question is already shared in the post:-

[http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5905/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer-registration-form](http://Reference%20URL)

You did not explained is it for Magento 2, or Magento 1

### In the same post Sylvain Rayé shared the piece of code along with git from where you can download the code to do so.

Answer he shared:-

To allow to publish an attribute in the register form and some others form page, you have to set that the attribute(s) is/are available to those forms.

To do that here is a sample code to put in your sql setup below. You can find the rest of the code I used for my [Magento Username module](https://github.com/diglin/Diglin_Username/) on my github account.

```
/* @var $installer Diglin_Username_Model_Entity_Setup */

$installer = $this;

/* @var $eavConfig Mage_Eav_Model_Config */

$eavConfig = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config');

$store = Mage::app()->getStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$attributes = $installer->getAdditionalAttributes();

foreach ($attributes as $attributeCode => $data) {
    $installer->addAttribute('customer', $attributeCode, $data);

$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('customer', $attributeCode);
$attribute->setWebsite( (($store->getWebsite()) ? $store->getWebsite() : 0));

if (false === ($attribute->getIsSystem() == 1 && $attribute->getIsVisible() == 0)) {
    $usedInForms = array(
        'customer_account_create',
        'customer_account_edit',
        'checkout_register',
    );
    if (!empty($data['adminhtml_only'])) {
        $usedInForms = array('adminhtml_customer');
    } else {
        $usedInForms[] = 'adminhtml_customer';
    }
    if (!empty($data['adminhtml_checkout'])) {
        $usedInForms[] = 'adminhtml_checkout';
    }

    $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $usedInForms);
}
$attribute->save();
```

}

Comment: Sure. I am not promoting any body here, but I am aware of a very good module online available that could help you out. You can try this:-

http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/